# Linking CSS in Wordpress with PHP and bloginfo()

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to link my CSS file with my header.php file for a Wordpress site I'm working on, but I'm having a little trouble following along.

I was told to set it up like so:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Below is my current code:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

However if you look at the current state of the site, http://thenerdup.com, it's obvious that the CSS file is not linked properly.

For what it's worth, this is the tutorial I'm following along with: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial

I'm currently on the part about editing the header.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm currently having this same problem with this same tutorial. No style.css whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it should be

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

So it'll `echo/print` the `url` of your `stylesheet`.

Here `bloginfo()` is a function and `stylesheet_url` is a parameter of this function. There are other parameters too, for example if you write `bloginfo('name')` then it'll print the name of your blog.

Also you can use

```
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri();?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Read more [at Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo).

Comment: thanks, i guess i should have just followed the directions, haha.